# How to solve an integral over a distribution function

Tags: integration

To find the reservation wage $w^*$ in a search labour model it is possible to derive the following expression

$ w^* = b + \frac{\lambda}{\rho + \eta} \int_{w^*} (w-w^*)dG(w), \hspace{15mm} (1)$

where $b=-1 , \lambda=0.2, \rho=0.005 \hspace{1mm}$  and  $\hspace{1mm} \eta=0.02$. Further, $G(w)\sim LN(1,1)$, that is a log-normal distribution with $\mu=1$ and $\sigma=1$. The pdf of such distribution is $\frac{1}{x \sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} exp\Big(-\frac{(ln(x)-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}\Big)$.

In this example the solution is (apparently) $w^* = 7.439$ with a [graphical representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vD9S.png). It should not be possible to find an analytical solution. I have two main questions

(A) $\textbf{What does it mean to integrate over a distribution?}$

I do not need a full theoretical explanation, but more of a "how to handle this". I have found some answers that suggest inserting the pdf of the distribution in the place of x (which in this example is w) and integrate over x. I.e.

$ w^* = b + \frac{\lambda}{\rho + \eta} \int_{w^*} (\frac{1}{w \sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} exp\Big(-\frac{(ln(w)-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}\Big)-w^*)dw,$

However I cannot confirm this.

(B) $\textbf{How to handle the semi-definite integral?}$

Combined it is generally a question of

(=) $\textbf{How to solve for $w^*$ in equation (1)?}$.

Any comments or helpful suggestions is very much appreciated! It is my first time posting here, so bear that in mind.

Best regards

Comment: I guess you mean $\displaystyle\int^\infty_{w^*} (w-w^*)dG(w)$. Your "graphical solution" is not very precise, $7.4595$ is better.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

The "graphical solution" is from a textbook where, I have also found the example.
Would you care to explain how you found 7.4595?

Also, it may be that semi-definite refers to $\int^w_{w^*}$ following the explanation in another [thread](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/24312/purpose-of-semidefinite-integral).

best regards

Comment: You didn't comment on my guess what your notation really means. BTW, $$\displaystyle\int^\infty_{w^*} (w-w^*)dG(w)=\int^\infty_{w^*} (w-w^*)G'(w)\,dw,$$ naturally, where $G'(w)$ is exactly the pdf you mentioned. The integral can be written in terms of the (complementary) cdf of the standard normal distribution, but your equation can be solved only numerically.

Comment: @qfwfq I really appreciate your help! (1) $\textbf{notation}$: To be honest, I do not know for sure, what the notation means - it is not my own. The thread I linked to refers to $\int_a g(x)dx = \int^x_a g(s) ds$, but I am not sure whether this or your suggestsion is "correct" in this case. (2) $\textbf{solution}$: I understand the pdf to cdf. Do you just integrate $wG'(w)$ and $w^*G'(W)$ and insert numbers? I will try to use your suggestion today. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in a comment, I interpreted the integral as $$\displaystyle\int^\infty_{w^*} (w-w^*)dG(w)=\int^\infty_{w^*} (w-w^*)G'(w)\,dw=\int^\infty_{w^*} w\,G'(w)\,dw-w^*\,\int^\infty_{w^*} G'(w)\,dw,$$ where
$$G'(w)=\frac{1}{w\,\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{(\ln w-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}\right).$$ The rightmost integral can be written in terms of the complementary cdf of standard normal distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function) as $\displaystyle Q\left(\frac{\ln w^*-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$, the other one can be rewritten, using $w=\exp(\ln w)$ and
$$\ln w-\frac{(\ln w-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}=\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}2-\frac{(\ln w-\mu-\sigma^2)^2}{2\sigma^2},$$ as $\displaystyle \exp\left(\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}2\right)\,Q\left(\frac{\ln w^*-\mu-\sigma^2}{\sigma}\right)$. Then, the equation becomes
$$w^*=-b+c\,\exp\left(\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}2\right)\,Q\left(\frac{\ln w^*-\mu-\sigma^2}{\sigma}\right)-c\,w^*\,Q\left(\frac{\ln w^*-\mu}{\sigma}\right),$$ where $\displaystyle c=\frac{\lambda}{\rho + \eta}$.

The equation can be solved only numerically. With your numerical values, $c=8$, and in Pari/GP, I'd write

```
solve(x=1,10,-x-1+4*exp(1.5)*erfc((log(x)-2)/sqrt(2))-4*x*erfc((log(x)-1)/sqrt(2)))
```

(since $\displaystyle Q(x)=\frac12\,\operatorname{Erfc}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$) with result $7.4594961135988564221204777767475134525$.