# Solving definite integrals over a distribution

Tags: calculus

I am to solve the following equation

\begin{align}
x = d + c \Big(\int^e_{a} (a-x)dG(b)+\gamma \int^\infty_{e} (b-x)dG(b) \Big), \hspace{15mm} (1)
\end{align}

by finding a value for x. a, c, d and $\gamma$ are known constants and e is given by

\begin{align}
e = \frac{a-(1-\gamma)x}{\gamma}
\end{align}

Furthermore, $G(b)\sim LN(1,1)$, that is a log-normal distribution with $\mu=1$ and $\sigma=1$. Its P.D.F. is defined defined as

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x \sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} exp\Big(-\frac{(ln(x)-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}\Big) \
\end{align}

A VERY helpful member has helped me understand that (1) can be stated as:

\begin{align}
x = d + \underbrace{c \cdot a\int^e_{a}G'(b)db -c\cdot x\int^e_{a}G'(b)db}_K+\underbrace{c\gamma\int^\infty_{e}bG'(b)db - c\gamma \cdot x\int^\infty_{e}G'(b)db}_Z \hspace{15mm} (2)
\end{align}

where G'(b) is equal to the defined P.D.F. above.

From the solution to my earlier question (which can be found following this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4048787/how-to-solve-an-integral-over-a-distribution-function).) I am able to write out the last two terms as

\begin{align}
Z = c\gamma \cdot exp \bigg(\mu + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\bigg)Q\bigg(\frac{ln(e)-\mu-\sigma^2}{\sigma}\bigg)-c \gamma \cdot x Q\bigg(\frac{ln(e)-\mu}{\sigma}\bigg), \hspace{15mm} (3)
\end{align}

where $Q(y) = \frac{1}{2}Erfc \Big(\frac{y}{\sqrt 2}\Big)$ (Link to [Q-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function) and [Error Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)). This is possible since the integral is defined for b to $\infty$ as I understand it, hence I cannot use the exact same approach for the first two terms.

$\textbf{The problem and question is then}$, how may I handle the first two integrals (K) in (2) defined on the interval a to b so I can find the solution numerically?

I had the idea to rewritte the integrals to

\begin{align}
x = c \cdot a\Big[\int^\infty_{a}G'(b)db-\int^\infty_{e}G'(b)db \Big] \\
 -c\cdot x\Big[\int^\infty_{a}G'(b)db-\int^\infty_{e}G'(b)db\Big]
\end{align}

and then use the Q-solution from previous

\begin{align}
x = c \cdot a\Big[Q\bigg(\frac{ln(a)-\mu}{\sigma}\bigg)-Q\bigg(\frac{ln(e)-\mu}{\sigma}\bigg) \Big] \\
 -c\cdot x\Big[ Q\bigg(\frac{ln(a)-\mu}{\sigma}\bigg)-Q\bigg(\frac{ln(e)-\mu}{\sigma}\bigg)\Big]
\end{align}

However, a should be able to take values below 1, so this might not be the correct approach.

Any comments or helpful suggestions is very much appreciated! It is one of my first times posting here, so bear that in mind.

Best regards